# Using custom data-attribute value based on popover selection - not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

'm trying to use the custom data attribute value based on the the selection made on the options displayed in the popover.

Here in the below example I've a message reading "I am **single** with no kids" where on clicking **single** a popover appears with the option **(single / married)**. If the user clicks **married**, then **I am** should be replaced with **We are** MARRIED with no kids

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7fVL/)

## HTML

```
<div>
        <span id="m-marital-status" data-single="I am" data-multiple= "We are">I am</span>
        <div class="section-input">
            <div class="popover-markup" id="marital-status"><a href="#" class="trigger">Single</a> with 
                <div class="head hide"></div>
                <div class="content hide">
                    <ul>
                      <li>married</li>
                      <li>single</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="footer hide">test</div>
                </div>
                <span>no Kids</span>.
            </div>
        </div>
```

## CSS

```
.popover-title {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

## JS

```
$('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }

});
```

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M2Gk6/1/

Comment: how to change 'single' to 'married' after selecting 'married' option from list?

Comment: see the updated answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
            <ul class="marital-status">
                <li data-status="We are">married</li>
                <li data-status="I am">single</li>
            </ul>
```

then

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.marital-status li', function () {
    $('#m-marital-status').css('color', 'red').html($(this).data('status'));
    $('#marital-status .trigger').text($(this).text())
    $('.popover-markup>.trigger').popover('hide')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M2Gk6/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to delegate the click event to the popover content with something like:

```
$('body').on("click", ".popover li", function() {
  // Code here
})
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7fVL/3/

Comment: how to change 'single' to 'married' after selecting 'married' option from list?

Answer (score 0):

What it happens is that you get the html of the popup as a string and pass it to Bootstrap. It later creates another div where it puts this content. And there are two problems with this. You are trying to attach the events before the popup is shown. And your selector for the click events is actually matching the html markup prepared for the popup, but not the actual DOM elements in the shown popup. Here is a solution of the problem:

```
trigger.popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    content: function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.popover-content li').click(function() {
                closePopup();
                $('#m-marital-status').css('color','red');
            });
        }, 500);
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();        
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7fVL/4/